# Redis Lettuce TimeoutOptions versus Spring commandTimeout in cluster deployment

Tags: kotlin, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

In Lettuce, there are various timeout settings, primarily focusing on connection timeouts and command timeouts. When I attempted to configure Lettuce, I discovered that there are two distinct types of timeouts available, as shown below in the provided Kotlin code:

```kotlin
fun lettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer(): LettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer {
    return LettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer { builder ->
        val topologyRefreshOptions = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
            .enablePeriodicRefresh(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .dynamicRefreshSources(true)
            .build()
        val timeoutOptions = TimeoutOptions.builder()
            .timeoutCommands()
            .fixedTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
            .build()
        val socketOption = SocketOptions.builder()
            .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .build()
        val clientOptions = ClusterClientOptions.builder()
            .topologyRefreshOptions(topologyRefreshOptions)
            .timeoutOptions(timeoutOptions)
            .socketOptions(socketOption)
            .build()

        builder.clientOptions(clientOptions)
        builder.commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
    }
}
```

In above, I think that timeout for `socketOption` is connection timeout. But how about the timeout for `TimeoutOptions` and `builder.commandTimeout()` ? both are saying that 'this is for command timeout' and I can't find out any differences. I guess `builder.commandTimeout` is for global configuration and `timeoutOptions` is for more granular configuration which means 'specifying timeout per commands'. Is this right ?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836375/redis-client-lettuce-command-timeout-versus-socket-timeout) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe that is about the difference between command timeout vs socket timeout. I'm asking about command timout but using `timeout options on lettuce` vs `command timeout on spring`

Comment: Additionally, there is the io.lettuce.core.api.StatefulConnection#setTimeout method. 

I'm not entirely clear on the differences, but from my experience, it appears that there is a hierarchy of priority between them.